# login into instagram with different ip address

Tags: python, proxy, instagram, ip-address, instagram-api

My  code:

```
DEVICE = {
'instagram_version': '26.0.0.10.86',
'android_version': 24,
'android_release': '7.0',
'dpi': '640dpi',
'resolution': '1440x2560',
'manufacturer': 'samsung',
'device': 'SM-G930F',
'model': 'herolte',
'cpu': 'samsungexynos8890'
}

USER_AGENT_BASE = (
'Instagram {instagram_version} '
'Android ({android_version}/{android_release}; '
'{dpi}; {resolution}; {manufacturer}; '
'{device}; {model}; {cpu}; en_US)'
)

user_agent = USER_AGENT_BASE.format(**DEVICE)
LOGIN_URL = 'https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/accounts/login/'
sess = requests.Session()
sess.headers.update(REQUEST_HEADERS)
sess.headers.update({'User-Agent': user_agent})
response = sess.post(LOGIN_URL, data=data)
assert response.status_code == 200
```

It allows me to login into an Instagram account with my original ip address. How do I change or hide my ip?

Comment: Are you currently using a vpn provider that offers `socks`? If so, you can look into using the [PySocks](https://pypi.org/project/PySocks/) package.